# What is the value of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)x^n}{n!}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to find the value of the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)x^n}{n!}$.I've computed its radius of convergence which comes out to be zero.

I'm not getting how to make adjustments in the general terms of the series to get the desired result...

Comment: *Is it* zero? Or is it $\frac1{0}$ ?

Comment: Think about the exponential function and it's series expansion around zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint

$$\dfrac{(n+1)x^n}{n!}=x\cdot\dfrac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}+\dfrac{x^n}{n!}$$

Now $$e^y=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\dfrac{y^r}{r!}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n$ the sequence in the series.

Now $a_n=\frac{z^n}{(n-1)!}+\frac{z^n}{n!}$

Now $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{nz^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{(n-1)!}=z\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{k!}=ze^z$

Also $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{k!}=e^z$

So the whole sum is $(z+1)e^z$

Answer (score 1):

Is it not so that you can split the sum into two and simplify:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(n+1)x^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{nx^n}{n!} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n}}{(n-1)!} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}= \ldots$$

Considering what reindexing the first sum to start at 0 is, and knowing the expansion for $x \mapsto e^x$ will see you well!

Answer (score 1):

$$y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{nx^n}{n!}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
$$y=e^x+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{nx^n}{n!}$$
$$\frac{y}{x}=\frac{e^x}{x}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{nx^{n-1}}{n!}$$
$$\frac{y}{x}=\frac{e^x}{x}+e^x$$
so
$$y=e^x+xe^x$$